# Simple MATLAB Variable Question

Tags: matlab

Please help me write a MATLAB program that constructs a column matrix *b*, such that

> b<sub>1</sub> = 3x<sub>1</sub> - 3/4y<sub>0</sub>
>   b<sub>2</sub> = 3x<sub>2</sub>
>   ...
>   b<sub>n-2</sub> = 3x<sub>n-2</sub>
>   b<sub>n-1</sub> = 3x<sub>n-1</sub> - 3/4y<sub>n</sub>

where *x* and *y* are variables. Notice that *y* only appears in the first and last entries of *b*.

My problem is that I don't know how variables work in MATLAB. I tried

> b = 3*x

and it says

> ??? Undefined function or variable 'x'

So, how do we create variables instead of constants?

Thanks!

Comment: Okay, good luck!  Wait, did you have a question?

Comment: Ok, let's rewind a bit. What are you trying to do? What is `x`, what is `y` and how do you get `x` and `y`?

Comment: They are variables, so that if I call *b(2)* for example, it will return >3x<sub>2</sub>. Is this possible?

Comment: is it possible in MATLAB doing something like `y = 1+x`, then y^2 will give me `>1 + 2x + x^2`? All in the terms of _x_.

Comment: Yes, it is possible (in a limited way). You'll need to use the [symbolic toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/products/symbolic/), which is not part of basic MATLAB. Can you check if you have that toolbox? In the mean time, I'll post a simple example on how to use it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### EDIT:

From your comments above, what you need is MATLAB's [symbolic toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/products/symbolic/), which allows you to perform computations in terms of variables (without assigning an explicit value to them). Here's a small example:

```
syms x %#declare x to be a symbolic variable
y=1+x;
z=expand(y^2)

z=
 
x^2 + 2*x + 1
```

You will need to use `expand` sometimes to get the full form of the polynomial, because the default behaviour is to keep it in its simplest form, which is `(1+x)^2`. Here's another example to find the roots of a general quadratic

```
syms a b c x
y=a*x^2+b*x+c;
solve(y)

ans =
 
 -(b + (b^2 - 4*a*c)^(1/2))/(2*a)
 -(b - (b^2 - 4*a*c)^(1/2))/(2*a)
```

---

I think you meant `bn` and `xn` in the last line... Anyway, here's how you do it:

```
b=3*x;
b([1,end])=b([1,end])-3/4*y([1,end])
```

You can also do it in a single line as

```
b=3*x-3/4*[y(1); zeros(n-2,1); y(end)];
```

where `n` is the length of your vector.

Answer (score 0):

You never stated your problem...

Anyways just set the first entry of b individually first. Then use a loop to set the next values of b from 2 up to n-2. Then set the last entry of b individually.

On a side note, if x is a vector, you can simply vectorize the loop part.