# What is the proper way to simplfy the expression 'x' plus 'x' in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, simplification

I have a very simple question: I'm trying to simplify the expression `x + x` to get the answer `2x` in MATLAB but I'm having a hard time figuring out the proper format and I don't know what to search in the documentation files for an answer.

Comment: If you're trying to keep `x` as a variable (i.e., no values assigned), then you need the symbolic toolbox for MATLAB. I gave a very simple example of how to use it in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6462250/simple-matlab-variable-question/6462278#6462278). Let me know if your question is related to that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### EDIT:

From the comments below, it looks like you need the symbolic toolbox. A basic example can be found [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6462250/simple-matlab-variable-question/6462278#6462278). Once `x` is set to be a symbolic variable, `x+x` should give you `2*x`.

#### Original answer:

Your question, as it stands, is not very clear. I'll interpret your question to mean the following:

> Mathematically, `x+x` is `2x`. How do I write `2x` in MATLAB?

In MATLAB, arithmetic operations need to be explicitly stated. The operator for scalar multiplication is `*` and you would write the above as `2*x`. [Here is the documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/arithmeticoperators.html) for the various arithmetic operations, and their rules & syntaxes. For the most part, if you're familiar with linear algebra, you'll find MATLAB pretty easy to use.

If I'm mistaken and you meant something else, please edit your question to clarify (and/or leave a comment here) and I'll update my answer.

Comment: I believe he's asking how can he ask Matlab to give him `2*x` given an input of `x+x`. Something aking to Mathematica's `Simplify`.

Comment: @Pablo: I thought so too and left a comment asking him about that (now removed). But then I checked in the symbolic toolbox and it does not return `x+x`. `2*x` is the simplest form and it returns that without having to use `expand` or `simplify`. So I assumed the question was related to something else.

Comment: @Pablo: It could also be the case that OP is not aware of the symbolic toolbox and tried using `x` as a variable, in which case MATLAB will give an undefined variable error.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. Hopefully this makes more sense. I'm trying to make MATLAB simplify the expression x+x. The output should be 2x. For example 3x+2x should equal 5x. How would i perform operations such as these? Thanks again.

Comment: @mysticxhobo: Do you have the symbolic toolbox? Did you try looking at the link in my comment on the question?

Comment: @yoda im attempting to figure out if i have it. ill reply back in a few minutes.

Comment: @yoda your explanation worked perfectly i used the syms toolbox to set x as a symbolic variable and performed the operation x+x and MATLAB returned 2*x. Thanks!

Comment: @yoda It seems you were right :) I don't have the symbolic toolbox so I couldn't check.